# iAd Banner hidden under MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, adbannerview

I have a view where I show a MPMoviePlayerController with the following code:

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player  = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
[[player view] setFrame:self.view.bounds];
[self.view addSubview: [player view]];
[player play];
```

Then I show an iAd Banner using the delegates and it actually shows if I don't add the player. So the iAd Banner is under the player. I need it to be shown over the player view, it has to cover part of the played video.

Is that possible fellas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I got the position of the two views:

```
NSInteger indexOfControl1 = [[self.view subviews] indexOfObject:banner];
NSInteger indexOfControl2 = [[self.view subviews] indexOfObject:mediaPlayer.view];
NSLog(@"Banner: %ld",(long)indexOfControl1);
NSLog(@"Media Player: %ld",(long)indexOfControl2);
```

and then I moved the banner above the last view with the following code:

```
[self.view insertSubview:banner aboveSubview:mediaPlayer.view];
```

Thank you anyway, hope it helps someone else.